# Spring kafka application with multiple consumer groups stops consuming messages

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, producer-consumer

**kafka version 2.3.1
Spring boot verison: 2.2.5.RELEASE**

I have spring boot Kafka application with 3 consumer groups. It stops consuming messages because of failing heartbeat. I tried updating the consumer configuration suggested by multiple stack overflow threads. Even after that, I am facing the issue. In the configuration,

Consumers are taking less than one second as per log to consume a message till the point they are being consumed and suddenly it stops. Also, some of the processing in the consumer happening in an asynchronous thread

Below is the configuration for one of the consumer factories.
I gave 10 seconds buffered time for each record and based on that configured MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> reqConsumerFactory()
    {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "req-event-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "req-event-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerConfig.getBootstrapAddress());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); 
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 50*15*1000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 50*10*1000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 50);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);

    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>> reqKafkaListenerContainerFactory()
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(reqConsumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(2));
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        return factory;
    }
```

One of the consumer method

```
    @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "${process.update.requirement.topic.name}", containerFactory = "reqKafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId = "req-event-group")
    public void handleCompleteAndErrorRequirement(ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord,Acknowledgment acknowledgment)
    {
        RequirementEventMsg requirementEventMsg = (RequirementEventMsg)consumerRecord;
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        
        //asynchronous method call here
    }
```

I don't see any error other than this

```
2020-06-23 13:28:06.815 [INFO ] AbstractCoordinator:855 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=process-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2020-06-23 13:28:06.835 [INFO ] AbstractCoordinator:855 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=process-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2020-06-23 13:28:07.175 [INFO ] ConsumerCoordinator:472 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=process-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [UPDATE_REQUIREMENT_TOPIC-1, UPDATE_REQUIREMENT_TOPIC-0]
2020-06-23 13:28:07.176 [INFO ] KafkaMessageListenerContainer:394 - partitions revoked: [UPDATE_REQUIREMENT_TOPIC-1, UPDATE_REQUIREMENT_TOPIC-0]
2020-06-23 13:28:07.177 [INFO ] AbstractCoordinator:509 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=process-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
2020-06-23 13:28:07.233 [INFO ] ConsumerCoordinator:472 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=process-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [PROCESS_EVENT_TOPIC-0, PROCESS_EVENT_TOPIC-1]
2020-06-23 13:28:07.233 [INFO ] KafkaMessageListenerContainer:394 - partitions revoked: [PROCESS_EVENT_TOPIC-0, PROCESS_EVENT_TOPIC-1]
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the following: When you say it suddenly stops consuming, 1) what is the time gap/message gap between from the  moment app started running and this happening? 2) Is this happening every time more or less on the same gap?

Comment: Also explain what you mean by this `>because of failing heartbeat.` - since KIP-62, heartbeats are decoupled from the polling and they run on a separate thread. There is no point in finessing the `max.poll.interval` like that; just set it large enough that your listener will not take that long and small enough for the broker to detect a truly dead consumer in a reasonable time.

Comment: Heartbeat failing messages are repeated and Kafka rebalaces the consumer group. I updated the max poll interval to solve the issue of rebalancing but it did not  work

Comment: @Kavitakaran it happens every time when more than  30-40 messages are received within a second.

Comment: I am looking at the number of hearbeats without session.timeout.ms and is 3 based on Kafka's default consumer values. But you have a ratio of 50.  So I don't think your failure is due to heatbeat failure. And also. i.e it says hearbeat failed due to rebalancing. So the question is what caused the rebalancing which then caused the heartbeat to fail? May we worth checking the logs much further up(at least 500s further up) because of your settings it will take long time for kafka to detect failure and cause rebalancing (